# Issue with form action | 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress

Path to put form code:

```
public_html/wp-content/plugins/latepoint/lib/views/customers/dashboard.php
```

code form:

```
     <form action="update_domain.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">Old domain</label>
                        <input type="text" name="olddomain" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                           <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">New domain</label>
                        <input type="text" name="newdomain" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                           <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Data</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Below path to action code:

```
public_html/wp-content/plugins/latepoint/lib/views/customers/update_domain.php
```

Now when I click on sumbit and try run form then I get error:

```
URL: mywebsite.com/customer-dashboard/updatedomain.php
```

404
Looks like you are lost.
We can’t seem to find the page you’re looking for.

Comment: please, can you  share more details about your pages locations each to other  , did their are in same folder !?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use wordpress template files and put the code inside each template. (dashboard page and update page) It seems to me that you are trying to use wordpress outside wordpress logic.